# Video application doesn't open on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: video, 17.10

Recently I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on a VMWare workstation.

I upgraded the OS and installed codecs but the video application doesn't open.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which video application? Could please try to run the application in a terminal and [edit] your question to include any potential program output? The executable name and command to run the default video player in Ubuntu is `totem`.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in the default video player Totem on wayland. [Totem player not working in Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980080/totem-player-not-working-in-wayland)

If this is your problem you can either run Ubuntu 17.10 on Xorg where Totem works or set VLC to be the default video player on Ubuntu on Wayland.

Comment: thank you so much. I just run on Xorg and everything works fine. Please iluminate me, diference between Xorg vs Wayland? thanxs again.